# angular ctx.cart.getQuantity is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am implementing a simple Fruit Shop web application using Angular in which I am experiencing a strange exception on which I have spent lots of time, but have NOT found any solution yet.

The overall application's scenario is as follows:

In the root route (page) I am loading a bunch of fruits (each fruit is shown like [Bootstrap Card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)), among which the end-user can choose and add them to his/her Cart (through `Add to Card`, `-` and `+` buttons); and then he/she can go to his/her Cart to checkout and payment process.

My important implemented `components` are as follows:

- `products` (which is loaded as main component in app component and plays the main page role of the application)
- `productCard` (which plays the Bootstrap Card role and is loaded in `products` component using an `*ngFor`
- `productQuantity` (which provides the `Add to Card`, `-` and `+` buttons inside the `productCard` component. I have implemented this feature as a component, as I want to use this feature in the Cart page, allowing the end-use to add or subtract his/her choices there, too)

I have also implemented some simple models to play the entity roles as follows:

- cart.ts (The most important properties and methods of this class are `CartItem[]` array to persist the items chosen by the end-user inside his/her cart, and also `getQuantity(product: Product)` method that gets a product and returns a number which refers to the total number of that product inside the end-user's cart at the time)
- cart-item.ts (The most important properties of this class are `Quantity` and `Product` properties)
- product.ts (The most important properties of this class are `Name` and `Fee` properties.

Here are the codes be more clear for you:

`Products Component Class:`

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Cart } from '../models/cart';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[];
  filteredProducts: Product[];
  productsSubscription: Subscription;
  cartSubscription: Subscription;
  cart: Cart;

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    public auth: AuthService,
    private cartService: ShoppingCartService) {

  }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredProducts = (query) ?
      this.products.filter(p => p.Name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
      this.products;
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      (await this.cartService.getCart())
        .subscribe(cart => {
          this.cart = cart;

          this.productService.getAll().then(v =>
            v.subscribe(products => {
              this.filteredProducts = this.products = products
            }));
        });
    }
  }
}
```

`Products Component Markup:`

```
<h4>Welcome to Fruit Shop. <ng-container *ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn()"> To purchase fruits you must <span>log in first</span>.</ng-container></h4>
<p>
    <input type="text" #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" 
        placeholder="Type here to search among products..." class="form-control">
</p>
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts">
        <div class="col">
            <product-card [product]="p" [cart]="cart"></product-card>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

`ProductCard Component Class:`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Cart } from '../models/cart';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent {
  @Input('product') product: Product;
  @Input('cart') cart: Cart;

  constructor(public cartService: ShoppingCartService, public auth: AuthService) {

  }

  async addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.product).subscribe(
      res => this.cartService.getCart().then(
        res => {
          res.subscribe(c => this.cart = c)
        }).then(value => this.cartService.totalCartItems += 1)
    );
  }
}
```

`ProductCard Component Markup:`

```
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.Name }}</h5>
        <span class="card-text">{{ product.Fee | currency }}</span>
        <button 
            *ngIf="cart && cart.getQuantity(product) > 0" 
            (click)="cartService.deleteFromCart(product)" 
            type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button *ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn() || (cart && cart.getQuantity(product)) === 0; else updateQuantity"
            [ngClass]="!auth.isLoggedIn() ? 'button-not-allowd' : 'button-cursor'" 
            [disabled]="!auth.isLoggedIn()"
            (click)="addToCart() " class="btn btn-primary btn-block ">Add to Cart</button>

        <ng-template #updateQuantity>
            <product-quantity [product]="product" [cart]="cart"></product-quantity>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

`ProductQuantity Component Class:`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { Cart } from '../models/cart';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-quantity',
  templateUrl: './product-quantity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-quantity.component.css']
})
export class ProductQuantityComponent {

  @Input('product') product: Product;
  @Input('cart') cart: Cart;

  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) { 

  }

  async addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.product).subscribe(
      res => this.cartService.getCart().then(
        res => {
          res.subscribe(c => this.cart = c)
        }).then(value => this.cartService.totalCartItems += 1)
    );
  }

  subtractFromCart() {
    this.cartService.subtractFromCart(this.product).subscribe(
      res => this.cartService.getCart().then(
        res => res.subscribe(c => this.cart = c)).then(value => this.cartService.totalCartItems -= 1)
    );
  }

  deleteFromCart() {
    this.cartService.deleteFromCart(this.product).subscribe(
      res => this.cartService.getCart().then(
        res => res.subscribe(c => this.cart = c))
          .then(value => this.cartService.totalCartItems -= 1)
    );
  }
}
```

`ProdcutQuantity Component Markup:`

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-2 ">
        <button (click)="cart.getQuantity(product) > 1 ? subtractFromCart() : deleteFromCart()"
            class="btn btn-secondary btn-block ">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center quantity-text">
        {{ cart.getQuantity(product) }} in cart
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 ">
        <button (click)="addToCart()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block ">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Cart Service` which is a service and is used to communicate to the server side of the application about cart related things:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Cart } from './models/cart';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {
  totalCartItems: number = 0;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
    if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.getCart().then(resp =>
        resp.subscribe(cart => cart.CartItems.forEach(item => this.totalCartItems += item.Quantity)))
    }
  }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    return this.http.post(
      `http://localhost/FruitShop/api/v1/CartItems/AddItemByItemId/?productId=${product.Id}`,
      {},
      httpOptions);
  }

  subtractFromCart(product: Product) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    return this.http.post(
      `http://localhost/FruitShop/api/v1/CartItems/SubstractItemByItemId/?productId=${product.Id}`,
      {},
      httpOptions);
  }

  deleteFromCart(product: Product) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    return this.http.post(
      `http://localhost/FruitShop/api/v1/CartItems/DeleteItemByItemId/?productId=${product.Id}`,
      {},
      httpOptions);
  }

  async getCart(): Promise<Observable<Cart>> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    return this.http.get<Cart>('http://localhost/FruitShop/api/v1/Cart/GetCart', httpOptions);
  }
}
```

`cart.ts` which is my cart model:

```
import { CartItem } from './cart-item';
import { Product } from './product';

export class Cart {
    Id: number;
    IsActive: Boolean;
    IsDeleted: Boolean;
    CreatedAt: Date;
    User_Id: number;
    Coupons_Id: number;
    CartItems: CartItem[];

    getQuantity(product: Product): number {
        let count: number = 0;

        this.CartItems
            .filter(ci => ci.Products_Id == product.Id)
            .forEach(i => {
                count += i.Quantity;
            });

        return count;
    }
}
```

`cart-item.ts` which is my CartItem model:

```
import { Product } from './product';

export class CartItem {

    constructor(
        public Id: number,
        public Quantity: number,
        public ModifiedAt: Date,
        public IsDeleted: Boolean,
        public Products_Id: number,
        public Carts_Id: number,
        public Products: Product
    )
    {}

    get totalPrice() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Products.Fee;
    }
}
```

`product.ts` which is my Product model:

```
export class Product {

    constructor(public Id: number, public Name: string, public Fee: number, public imageUrl: string){

    }
}
```

`Here is the exception` that I don't know how to solve it, after searching the web and google a lot:

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: ctx.cart.getQuantity is not a function
    at ProductCardComponent_Template (product-card.component.html:7)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11949)
    at refreshView (core.js:11796)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11527)
    at refreshView (core.js:11848)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13154)
    at refreshView (core.js:11819)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11527)
```

Comment: Can you share stackblitz URL for this?

Comment: @prathameshk73, I have not put the project on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `cart` isn't instantly available and comes from a `subscription` in `Products Component Class`. It means at the beginning in a moment of time it is `undefined` and `getQuantity` isn't a function.

Try the next thing to solve it: add `ngIf` on the `div.row`

`Products Component Markup:`

```js
<h4>Welcome to Fruit Shop. <ng-container *ngIf="!auth.isLoggedIn()"> To purchase fruits you must <span>log in first</span>.</ng-container></h4>
<p>
    <input type="text" #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" 
        placeholder="Type here to search among products..." class="form-control">
</p>
<div class="row" *ngIf="cart">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts">
        <div class="col">
            <product-card [product]="p" [cart]="cart"></product-card>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

now the product cart will be rendered only when the cart exists that shouldn't cause the error.

Comment: I did this, but the problem is still there.

Comment: magic :) do I understand right that the error comes in `product-card` component?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's also strange for me.

Comment: I see, in `addToCart` of the component, why do you reassign the cart? I would add there `console.log` to ensure that the cart is right object.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by instantiating the cart. For example, this.cart = new Cart(c.Id, c.IsActive, c.IsDeleted, c.CreatedAt, c.User_Id, c.Coupons_Id, c.CartItems), instead of this.cart = c. I did this in all cases that I needed such a thing.

Comment: That's great! glad to hear.